# What is the function to round 1.1 to 2?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want a function that will round numbers so that 1.01 will become 2.

1.99 will become 2, 
 0.99 will become 1, 
 etc.

So if a number has any decimals, it should be rounded to the next integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will work for you:

```
=ROUNDUP(A1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CEILING` provides the same functionality as `ROUNDUP` but is more straightforward for a range of increments (not different for this integer only case).

```
=CEILING(A1,1)
```

For this specific case it may be clearer still to use
    `=INT(A1)+1`